# Can proxy created by servicedelegate.getport reusable? is it Thread-safe?

Tags: java, web-services, proxy, websphere

We are using webservice (through websphere), to improve performance, we believe we can cache proxy created by servicedelegate.getport(..) since creating proxy every time is expensive.

Now, our question is, is it thread safe? Just image, we have 10 threads running at the same time, they will grab the same proxy, and use it at the same time.

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Instead of letting your application cache it, just have it injected using WebServiceRef and let the container manage it for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ports are not thread safe. They keep state, like `javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext`. But port object can be safely reused later!

Cache ports in `LinkedBlockingQueue` and `peek` before call and then return after with `offer`.

In following implementation `port` object doesn't leak out of `call` code so it is safe to reuse it:

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Port> portCache = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

public Rsp call(Req req) {
    Port port = portCache.poll();
    if (port == null) {
        port = createPort();
    }
    BindingProvider provider = (BindingProvider) port;
    try {
        return portMethod.invoke(port, req);
    } finally {
        portCache.offer(port);
    }
}
```